# How to Add Background - image to bootstrap Navbar first li element only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

can you please take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/LjWUs/74/) and following code and let meknow how I can add a backgrund image to only first `<li>` of the navbar?

```
.navbar-inner{
  background:none ! important;
}

li:first-child {
  background-image: url(http://themes/kids/images/lava-top.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LjWUs/76/).

```
.navbar .nav > li:first-child > a, .navbar .nav > li:first-child > a:hover, .navbar .nav > li:first-child > a:focus
{
    background-image: url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo6w.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x; 
}
```